# Navigate URL for Hyperlink is changeed, when the Title set to hyperlink has "/" inbetween?

Tags: asp.net, .net, hyperlink

I am using hyperlinks inside datalist and the datalist is binded with a datatable

```
    Hyperlink inside my datalist :

<asp:HyperLink ID="hypSubSections" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Pagename") + "?ID=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID") + "&Code=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CODE") + "&Title=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title") %>' Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

On Page load all the hyperlinks have correct navigate url set, When there is a case where the TItle set to hyperlink is "Criteria/Admission" and now I click that hyperlink, the Pagename value set to hyperlink is changed somehow and to all other hyperlinks from there..

The problem arises only when the text has slash inbetween. How to handle this ? It looks weird to me.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Text='<%# Server.HtmlEncode(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title")) %>'
```

Update:

how about setting the text not by attribute?

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hypSubSections" runat="server"><%# Server.HtmlEncode(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title")) %></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: I get this error : Character '%' (0x25) is not allowed at the beginning of an XML name

Comment: It has the same problem, the page name is replaced by the text after slash (Admission).